# Input password in terminal's password field without keyboard

Tags: shell, terminal

I have several temporary accounts in my PC which I use for testing and I switch in between them very frequently. Let say one of them is `test` and other is `test1`. I am working on `test` and I have to go to `test1`. Normally, I would do `su - test1` which will return a field `Password:` asking password for `test1`. Then I enter the password and hit `Enter`. Is there any way to store the password in a variable `pass` and feed it with `su` command to escape the `Password:` field?

**Note:** I am aware of the security risk involved in using it with `su` and saving password in a variable. I am not worried about them as they are just a few temporary accounts.

Comment: Other possible approaches include using `ssh` to log into the local machine so you can use `test`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or using `sudo -u test` instead of `su` because it can be configured with the `NOPASSWD` flag to not ask for the password.

Comment: thank you for suggesting `ssh` approach.

Answer (score 0):

`su` does `isatty(3)` to make sure the STDIN is actually refers to a TTY.

So you can't use any variable to pass the password to `su` via STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

So, I read [heemayl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/68757/heemayl) answer and was pritty disharted. Then I noticed [Ulrich Schwarz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3929/ulrich-schwarz) suggestion on doing it with `ssh`. Did some reading on `ssh` and stumbled on to something called `sshpass`.It takes the password and gives input to the ssh command. I would  going through the hole documentation/man page.

**Solve of My Problem:** Assuming my `password` for `test1` `1tset`, command for my problem will be: `sshpass -p '1tset' ssh test1@host`